# Exporting an Excel object to MS-Word with VBA

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to create a word document out of Excel findings, to do so I am going to use VBA to export out shapes with text.

I can get the Shape to get exported to the word document but the text is lost once it makes it to word. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong or need to add to get my shape to contain text once it reaches the Word document.

**Problem:** No text on my shapes once they are copied to word

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim embedWord As oleObject
Dim wordDocument As Object
```

*My word document is embedded into excel*

```
Set embedWord = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(1)
embedWord.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary

Set wordDocument = embedWord.Object

wordDocument.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test1.docx")

Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
wrdApp.Quit
```

*I save the word document and then assign it to my wrdApp*

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Documents.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test1.docx"
```

*This is a Rectangle that I can get copies over to word but no text is coming over with it.*

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Rectangle 8").Copy
With wrdApp
.Selection.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=Bookmark1 'Using a bookmark in the document
.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
.Selection.TypeBackspace 'This is my error without this code it works fine, I think the words are selected and when this line is ran it deletes the text inside the shape.
End With
wrdApp.Visible = True
wrdApp.Activate
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If this is even possible.

Thank you,
Joey

Comment: Why do you have that line `.Selection.TypeBackspace`?